# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _remap

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to open an image in python script but when importing skimage.io I get the following error. I have installed pip install scikit-image several times but I always get this error. Can anyone help me?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/BA Code/PSR-Staining/main.py", line 9, in 
> import skimage.io
> File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BA Code\PSR-Staining\venv\lib\site-packages\skimage_*init*_.py", line 127, in 
> from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
> File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BA Code\PSR-Staining\venv\lib\site-packages\skimage\util_*init*_.py", line 17, in 
> from ._map_array import map_array
> File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BA Code\PSR-Staining\venv\lib\site-packages\skimage\util_map_array.py", line 2, in 
> from ._remap import _map_array
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _remap: The given module is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `pip install msvc-runtime`? See discussion [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4780).